# I want to have number sequence as IDs in Spring Data MongoDB persistence layer. How to configure this behavior?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

Spring Data with MongoDB having BigInteger ids is still generating alphanumeric ObjectIds. I want to have number sequence as IDs. How to configure this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data MongoDB tries to convert all types that can make up `ObjectId`s by chance as they are recommended. As described in the MongoDB [reference documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers) this is due to the fact that they allow creating steadily increasing ids over a cluster. If you really need linear ids (1,2,3… not only steadily increasing ones) use a type of `Long` and create ids manually.

Answer (score 0):

As per the springdata doc:
An id property or field declared as BigInteger in the Java class will be converted to and stored as an ObjectId using a Spring Converter

What exactly are you trying to represent for the _id?
If it's just a large number, using a long value will enable to represent 64bit numbers.
If you need to represent values larger than 64bit, then they would have to be represented either as a String or BinData in mongo, but not ObjectId since that is a fixed 12 bytes.

Comment: I am depending on Spring to generate the IDs for me. I told it to generate IDs for BigInteger type, but it keeps generating object ids. How do I fix this?